# Missing State in Choropleth Map?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I'm plotting this choropleth map of all the U.S. states using the country's abbreviation codes instead of FIPS codes and it is missing the state Missouri, but I have it included in my dataset here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naymalabonna/CSC474-Final-Project/main/Data/Jail%20Data/covid_prison_rates.csv

I tried this with 2 choropleth maps and same issue with Missouri missing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfoTK.png)

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naymalabonna/CSC474-Final-Project/main/Data/Jail%20Data/covid_prison_rates.csv')
df.head()

data = dict(type ='choropleth',
            colorscale = 'electric',
            z = df['prisoner_cases_pct'],
            locations = df['name'],
            locationmode = 'USA-states',
            text = df['name'],
            marker = dict(line = dict(color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', width =1)),
            colorbar = {'title': 'Prisoner Cases Rates'})

layout = dict(title = 'Prisoner COVID-19 Cases Rates',
              geo = dict(scope ='usa'))

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data], layout = layout)
choromap.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Missouri is not showing up is because the state abbreviations in the data contain unnecessary white space; I ran it through your data in express and confirmed it.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
#from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naymalabonna/CSC474-Final-Project/main/Data/Jail%20Data/covid_prison_rates.csv')

df.name.unique() #'MO ' is error
array(['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'Federal', 'FL',
       'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD',
       'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO ', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
       'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN',
       'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY', 'National'],
      dtype=object)

df.loc[25,'name'] = 'MO'
fig = px.choropleth(locations=df.name.unique().tolist(),
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    color=df.name.unique().tolist(),
                    scope='usa')
fig.show()
```

[image]